# login.microsoftonline.com: Name or service not known

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, office365

I am trying to get token using authorization code from **office-365** using **Microsoft Graph API**.

The code i have written that successfully worked in local tomcat server but when i deployed the same code in google app-engine it gives me following error :

```
2019-04-26 17:27:01.608 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler: Exception message : login.microsoftonline.com: Name or service not known (ErrorHandler.java:14)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.608 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler: Error in class Class (ErrorHandler.java:15)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:930)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1325)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1278)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1194)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1128)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.609 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.610 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.610 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.610 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.610 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
2019-04-26 17:27:01.610 IST
com.sterlitesamlapp.commons.ErrorHandler errorHandler:   (ErrorHandler.java:18)
 org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
```

I wonder why this happening after deploying the code in app engine !
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Any solution to this?